# Show/Hide Div Elements with "php for" loop

Tags: php

I currently have 4 Divs. 1 Is always shown depending on the dropdown-menu option chosen, and the 3 rest are then hidden.

What I want is to show 2 divs if "2" is chosen, 3 divs shown if "3" is chosen, etc. I have a `php for` loop that I'm trying to take apart but I'm not sure how to go about it.

Here is an example:

```
<?php for($i=0; $i<4; $i++): ?>

<div class="<?php echo ($i>0?' hide':'') ?>">
This is Div <?php echo ($i+1) ?>.
</div>

<?php endfor; ?>
```

I'm aware that I will have to create 4 separate divs, but I don't know how to show/hide the ones depending on `$i`.

Comment: when you echo a div that you want hidden set a style="display:none" on the tag.  Set it to "block" if you want it visible.

Comment: Is there an intermediary page refresh (such as a form submission) between the point when someone picks which divs to show? If you want the elements to show/hide without a page refresh, then the hiding/showing will need to be done in javascript.

Comment: Hello, no there is no intermediary page. Let me see if I can find more code to post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php 
// $_GET["dropdown"] can be 1,2,3 or 4
$dropdown =  $_GET["dropdown"];



for($i=1; $i<=4; $i++): ?>

<div class="<?php echo ( $i > $dropdown ) ? 'hide':''; ?>">
This is Div <?php echo $i; ?>.
</div>

<?php endfor; ?>
```

**CSS**

```
.hide{
 display:none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If there is a trigger from drop down selected, then you need JavaScript to show and hide

```
 //code on html or ctp
 <div class="1" style="display:none;">
 <div class="2" style="display:none;">
 <div class="3" style="display:none;">
 <div class="4" style="display:none;">
```

on JavaScript

```
 <script type="text/javascript>
      //get the value from the dropdown-menu option 
      //some codes here
      var id = //value from the dropdown-menu option 

      if(id==1){
         $("1").show();
         $("2").hide();
         $("3").hide();
         $("4").hide();
      }
      else if(id == 2){
         $("1").hide();
         $("2").show();
         $("3").hide();
         $("4").hide();
      }
      else if(id == 3){
         $("1").hide();
         $("2").hide();
         $("3").show();
         $("4").hide();
      }
      else if(id == 4){
         $("1").hide();
         $("2").hide();
         $("3").hide();
         $("4").show();
      }
 </script>
```